# How to configure connection pool of H2 when starting from command line?

Tags: h2

I start H2 DB with TCP server. Looking at documentation I found how to set connection pool from java code.
I wonder: is it possible to create a connection pool from command line and set max number of connections in the pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I unterstand it a connection pool is a kind of a separate "client" that sits in front of the database and has one or more connections open. Your program asks the connection pool - and not the database - for a connection to the database. The connection pool looks if there is an unemployed connection hanging around and returns it to your program.

You just start the database as a "normal" TCP server as documented in http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server. But it's still up to you to write the [connection pool program](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connection_pool).